# Principal Component Analysis and determinant of the total scatter matrix

Tags: pca

Hi guys I'm reading a paper Eigenfaces vs. Fisherfaces: Recognition Using Class Specific Linear Projection, I'm wondering why in PCA the projection W is chosen to maximize the **determinant** of the total scatter matrix of the projected samples, i.e., arg max|W^T S_T W|(in latex form) where S_T is the scatter matrix of the original dataset.
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The expression makes sense if we note that the eigenvalues of a matrix can be found from the determinant using the characteristic equation.

#### (Quick review of PCA)

You probably know already that since we are performing a principle component analysis (PCA) of `S_T`, our goal is to find a diagonal matrix B such that

```
B = W^(T) * S_T * W
```

`W^(T)` is the transpose of W. The elements of the diagonal matrix B are the eigenvalues, and the column vectors of W are the eigenvectors. This gives us the Principal Components we seek.

#### Back to the characteristic equation:

The Determinant of a matrix can be used to find its eigenvalues from the characteristic equation. Quoting straight from wikipedia:

> [image]
>
> (where I is the identity matrix). Since v is non-zero, this means that the matrix I − A is singular, which in turn means that its determinant is 0 (non-invertible). Thus the roots of the function `det( I − A)` are the eigenvalues of A...
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial

Thus by maximizing the determinant, or finding its roots, you are able to find the eigenvalues.

#### Read more:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Relation_to_eigenvalues_and_trace
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors

Comment: Hi Aman, thanks for your answer, but why our goal is to find a diagonal matrix B? Why it's diagonal, can you give me a reference? I learn PCA from Duda's Pattern Classification book, in that book, they want the distance between original data and projected data to be minimized.

Comment: @Lenny - Sorry for delayed response, I somehow missed your comment. 

Imagine we have a collection of objects, each of which is described by 10 observable properties. Each object can be considered as a single point in the 10-dimensional property-space; each property is an axis in this space. 

But some properties may be correlated, so these axes are not orthogonal. Through PCA (using diagonalization), we find a new coordinate system in which each "principle" axis is based on a combination of the original properties, avoiding correlation and expressing maximum variation in fewer dimensions.

Comment: @Lenny - To learn more, check out (of course) wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis 
.. also, I liked the introduction to PCA in Chapter 14 of the O'Reilly book "Data Analysis with Open Source Tools", but it has not a general discussion but a specific use of PCA. 
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802363.do